# Generate SSRS Report Template programmatically in C#

Tags: reporting-services

I want to develop a number of reports in SSRS (200 plus reports) and each has a different number of columns, creating them one by one is taking much time and a tedious approach. Can I create a sample SSRS reports template programmatically in C#?

I have tried and created a function in C# but it didn't generate template correctly.

```
    private void GenerateRDLFile(ArrayList fieldList)
{
    FileStream fileStream = null;
    fileStream = File.OpenWrite("C:\\Users\\Imran\\source\\repos\\MyReports\\MyCust.rdl");
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    writer.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'");
    writer.WriteStartElement("Report");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("MustUnderstand", null, "df");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", null, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:rd", null, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:df", null, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:am", null, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/authoringmetadata");

    writer.WriteStartElement("am:AuthoringMetadata");
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    writer.WriteStartElement("am:CreatedBy");

    writer.WriteStartElement("am:Name");
    writer.WriteValue("SSDTRS");
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //am:Name

    writer.WriteStartElement("am:Version");
    writer.WriteValue("17.7.34003.232");
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //am:Version

    writer.WriteEndElement(); //am:CreatedBy
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    writer.WriteStartElement("am:UpdatedBy");

    writer.WriteStartElement("am:Name");
    writer.WriteValue("SSDTRS");
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //am:Name

    writer.WriteStartElement("am:Version");
    writer.WriteValue("17.7.34003.232");
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //am:Version

    writer.WriteEndElement(); //am:UpdatedBy
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    writer.WriteStartElement("am:LastModifiedTimestamp");
    writer.WriteValue(DateTime.Now);
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //am:LastModifiedTimestamp
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //am:AuthoringMetadata
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    writer.WriteStartElement("df:DefaultFontFamily");
    writer.WriteValue("Segoe UI");
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //df:DefaultFontFamily
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    writer.WriteStartElement("AutoRefresh");
    writer.WriteValue(0);
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //AutoRefresh
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    writer.WriteStartElement("DataSources");
    writer.WriteStartElement("DataSource");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", null, "MyCon");
    writer.WriteElementString("DataSourceReference", "MyCon");
    writer.WriteElementString("rd:SecurityType", "None");
    writer.WriteElementString("rd:DataSourceID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

    writer.WriteEndElement(); //DataSource
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //DataSources
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //DataSet Element
    writer.WriteStartElement("DataSets");
    writer.WriteStartElement("DataSet");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", null, "DataSet1");

    //Query Element
    writer.WriteStartElement("Query");
    writer.WriteElementString("DataSourceName", "MyCon");
    writer.WriteElementString("CommandType", "Text");
    writer.WriteElementString("CommandText", cmdText);
    writer.WriteElementString("Timeout", "30");
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //Query

    //Fields Elements
    writer.WriteStartElement("Fields");

    foreach (string fieldName in fieldList)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Field");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", null, fieldName);
        writer.WriteElementString("DataField", null, fieldName);
        writer.WriteElementString("rd:TypeName", null, fieldName.GetType().ToString());
        writer.WriteEndElement(); //end Field
    }
    //End previous elements
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //end Fields
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //end DataSet
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //end DataSets

    writer.WriteStartElement("ReportSections");
    writer.WriteStartElement("ReportSection");

    //Body element
    writer.WriteStartElement("Body");

    //ReportItems element
    writer.WriteStartElement("ReportItems");

    //Table element
    writer.WriteStartElement("Tablix");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", null, "Table1");

    writer.WriteStartElement("TablixBody");

    //Table Columns
    writer.WriteStartElement("TablixColumns");

    foreach (string fieldName in fieldList)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("TablixColumn");
        writer.WriteElementString("Width", "1.5in");
        writer.WriteEndElement(); //Tablix Column
    }

    writer.WriteEndElement(); //Tablix Columns

    //Header Row
    writer.WriteStartElement("TablixRows");
    writer.WriteStartElement("TablixRow");
    writer.WriteElementString("Height", ".25in");
    writer.WriteStartElement("TablixCells");

    foreach (string fieldName in fieldList)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("TablixCell");
        writer.WriteStartElement("ReportItems");

        //Textbox
        writer.WriteStartElement("Textbox");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", null, fieldName);
        writer.WriteElementString("CanGrow", "true");
        writer.WriteElementString("KeepTogether", "true");

        writer.WriteStartElement("Paragraphs");
        writer.WriteStartElement("Paragraph");
        writer.WriteStartElement("TextRuns");
        writer.WriteStartElement("TextRun");
        writer.WriteElementString("Value", fieldName);
        writer.WriteStartElement("Style");
        writer.WriteElementString("FontSize", "9pt");
        writer.WriteElementString("FontWeight", "Bold");

        writer.WriteEndElement(); //Style
        writer.WriteEndElement(); //TextRun
        writer.WriteEndElement(); //TextRuns
        writer.WriteEndElement(); //Paragraph
        writer.WriteEndElement(); //Paragraphs

        writer.WriteElementString("rd:DefaultName", fieldName);

        writer.WriteEndElement(); //Textbox
        writer.WriteEndElement(); //ReportItems
        writer.WriteEndElement(); //TablixCell
    }

    writer.WriteEndElement(); //TablixCells
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //TablixRow
    //writer.WriteEndElement(); //TablixRows
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //Tablix Body


    //Details Row
    //writer.WriteStartElement("TablixRows");
    writer.WriteStartElement("TablixRow");
    writer.WriteElementString("Height", ".25in");
    writer.WriteStartElement("TablixCells");

    foreach (string fieldName in fieldList)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("TablixCell");
        writer.WriteStartElement("ReportItems");

        //Textbox
        writer.WriteStartElement("Textbox");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", null, fieldName);

        writer.WriteStartElement("Style");
        writer.WriteEndElement(); //Style
        writer.WriteElementString("Top", "0in");
        writer.WriteElementString("Left", "0in");
        writer.WriteElementString("Height", ".5in");
        writer.WriteElementString("Width", "1.5in");
        writer.WriteElementString("Value", "=Fields!" + fieldName + ".Value");
        writer.WriteElementString("HideDuplicates", "DataSet1");
        writer.WriteEndElement(); //Textbox
        writer.WriteEndElement(); //ReportItems
        writer.WriteEndElement(); //TablixCell

    }

    //End Details element and children
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //TablixCells
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //TablixRow
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //TablixRows

    //End table element and end report definiation file
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //Table
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //ReportItems
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //ReportSection
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //ReportSections
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //Body
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //Report

    //Flush the writer and close the stream
    writer.Flush();
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hi There. Welcome to SharePoint stack exchange!  This is not the full answer, but it may help get  you there https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5302654/Auto-Generate-a-Lot-of-Columns-in-Reporting-Servic